# Easy question concerning notation(Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I have a very easy question concerning some notation I have been coming across in Abstract Algebra (Dummit & Foote)

Context: 
The relation between actions and homomorphisms may be reversed. Namely, given any nonempty set A and any homomorphism $\phi$ of the group $G$ into $S_A$ we obtain an action of G on A by defining $g \cdot a = \phi(g)(a)$

What, in simplest terms, is the meaning of $g \cdot a = \phi(g)(a)$?

I understand the meaning of $g \cdot a$ but am unclear about $\phi(g)(a)$

Comment: Can you give context? I'm guessing that $g \cdot a$ represents a group action, and that $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, $g \cdot a$ represents the group action. I will edit for clarity.

Comment: We are simply multiplying $\phi(g)$ by $a$? I am slightly confused by this since earlier it was stated that the expression $g \cdot a$ will be written as $ga$. This leads me to believe that $ \phi(g)(a) =\phi(g) \cdot a$ which would not be group multiplication.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't note that $\phi : G \to S_A$. Thus $\phi(g)$ is a permutation of the set $A$, and so it's a permutation acting on $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\phi : G \to S_A$, $\phi(g)$ is a permutation on the set $A$. That is, $\phi(g)$ is a bijection from $A$ to $A$, and so $\phi(g) a$ is the element that the permutation $\phi(g)$ sends $a$ to.